# How to create a script to capture packets using scapy and netinfo?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, scapy

Sory for my bad english. Perhaps issue has been resolved, but unfortunately I have not found a solution for my question.
In general, there was a problem with the task. Can someone help me?
Using scapy and netinfo, I need create functionality which sends ping requests to "8.8.8.8" host out of the default network interface in the system (something like 'ethX', where X is number) and verifies that the requests have been
sent by capturing outgoing packets.

with this step, I partly understood:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys 
from scapy.all import *
import netinfo
class test: 
    host = "8.8.8.8" 

    def pingh(self): 
        self.host 
        pkt = Ether()/IP(dst=self.host,ttl=(1,3))/ICMP() 
        ans,unans = srp(pkt,iface="eth0",timeout=2) 
        ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("%Ether.src% %IP.src%") ) 

r = test()
print "request from ping " 
r.pingh()
```

but at the next step I was stuck:

Do the same for 'lo' and 'ethX' interfaces simultaneously (use standard 'threading' module).
Captured results should be collected into dictionary which has the following structure:
{'iface1': list_of_captured_packets, 'iface2': list_of_captured_packets, ...}. Modification of this dictionary should be thread-safe. Modify the test class by adding a test which checks that resulting dictionary contains both - 'lo' and 'ethX' interfaces as keys.
P. S.
Don't let me die a fool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses the `threading` module to do two parallel `ping` tests, one on each of two interfaces.  For future work, use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module with `Pool()` and `imap_unordered()` -- it's a lot easier.

```
# INSTALL:
#   sudo apt-get install python-scapy
# RUN:
#   sudo /usr/bin/python ./pping.py

import sys, Queue, threading
from scapy import all as S

IFACE_LIST = 'wlan0','lo'


# pylint:disable=E1101
def run_ping(iface, out_q):
    host = '8.8.8.8'
    pkt = S.Ether()/S.IP(dst=host, ttl=(1,3))/S.ICMP() 
    ans,_unans = S.srp(pkt, iface=iface, timeout=2) 
    out_q.put( (iface,ans) )


result_q = Queue.Queue()
for iface in IFACE_LIST:
    threading.Thread(
        target=run_ping, args=(iface, result_q)
    ).start()

for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t != threading.current_thread():
        t.join()

print 'result:', dict( [
    result_q.get()
    for _ in range(result_q.qsize())
    ] )
```

Output:

```
Begin emission:
Begin emission:
..Finished to send 3 packets.
*Finished to send 3 packets.
...**
Received 5 packets, got 3 answers, remaining 0 packets
....................
Received 23 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 3 packets
result: {'lo': <Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>, 'wlan0': <Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:3 Other:0>}
```